# Why is the space complexity for this algorithm to check if an array has all unique characters O(n)?

Tags: java, algorithm, space-complexity

In the book "Cracking the Coding Interview", first exercise says "Implement an algorithm to determine if a string has all unique characters (not using additional data structures)". And the solution:

```
public static boolean isUniqueChars(String str) {
    boolean [] char_set = new boolean[256];
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        int val = str.charAt(i);
        if (char_set[val]) return false;
        char_set[val] = true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then they say "Time complexity is O(n), where n is the length of the string, and space complexity is O(n)".

I don't see why space complexity is O(n). The array `char_set` has a constant length, independent on how long the given `str` is. To me, space complexity is O(1).

Comment: I agree, it's constant. Unless you're considering the char array that backs String as included (I wouldn't, that's part of the input, not the algorithm)

Comment: I think str - O(n) and cha_set - O(1) then it's O(n), input also part of space complexity

Comment: Are you sure this is Java code?? Because then the solution is wrong. It assumes that charAt(i) returns an unsigned byte, but it really returns a char(2 bytes) , so char_set should be[256*256]. This also shows why the time use is really O(1) because, the max number of iterations is 256*256.

Comment: Looks *O(1)* to me...

Comment: @Eklavya The input is not part of the space complexity of the *method*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its space complexity is `O(1)` (`\Theta(1)`) as it keeps 256 (constant) bits more than the size of the input array. Also, the time complexity is `O(1)` as there are 256 chars to be checked in the input string and the duplicate will be detected at most at 256th character of the string.

Comment: But it will never scan more than 256 characters, no matter how long the input string is.

Comment: @MikeHarris The tighter bound is `O(1)`. However, `O(n)` was correct. Thanks. It's updated.